# Cant run xcopy or robocopy from Task Scheduler

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a vbs file used to copy files from a dropbox folder to a local folder. The vbs file:

```
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmd = "robocopy c:\users\Administrator\dropbox\sites C:\sites\XXX"
WshShell.Run cmd
```

The file runs fine when we run it manually by double clicking from the desktop (Windows Server 2012 R2) but does nothing when we try running it as a scheduled task.

Note: We believe this issue may have started when we did an upgrade from Windows server 2008 R2 to 2012 R2.

Comment: Use a batch script instead of VBScript, and have `robocopy` write a log file (`/log:`).

Comment: I cant do that. The script I attached is a simplification of the actual script which has logic and other stuff that can not be done using a batch script.

Comment: Even then you should have `robocopy` write a log, so it can tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Windows Server 2008, but with our Windows Server 2012 we have to `define the Startup Folder` when we use vbscript files (on Action tab if I remember right - just below where you define the arguments)

I just make it the folder where the script file exists

Hope that does it for you too.